# Show that $\sum_{n} u_n n^2 < + \infty$ under the assumption $\sum_{k = n}^{+ \infty} u_k \leq \frac{C}{n^{2+\epsilon}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $u_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Assume that there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $n \geq 0$ we have, for a fixed positive $\epsilon$,

$$\sum_{k = n}^{+ \infty} u_k  \leq \frac{C}{n^{2+\epsilon}}.$$

I would like to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} u_n n^2 < + \infty.$$

Any help or advices are welcome !

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Why do you think that the conclusion holds? Some *context* would be useful.

Comment: Yes I suppose they are positives. I can't give any clear context on this conclusion but the problem is self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute the following sum on $n$ :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} (2n-1) \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} u_k \leq C \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{2n-1}{n^{2+\epsilon}} < + \infty.$$

Working on the left side, we get, using Fubini's theorem :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} (2n-1) \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} u_k = \sum_{k= 1}^{+ \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k (2n-1) u_k = \sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} u_k k^2.$$

Therefore we have the result $\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} u_k k^2 < + \infty$.